# Counting triggers

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to count the number of triggers(both rising and falling) in the following plot:
[image: Plot]

Note: The plot might have unequal up-triggers,downfalls. So, I need the number of times, the value crossed '0' (14 in the plot)

Comment: So what have you tried? can you show your code? do you have the raw data which plotted the graph?

Comment: Are you simply looking for the number of times the y value of the graph is 14?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle , till now , i tried for looping over data and setting a counter aside but it is becoming computationally complex because , this data is a part of an image like this : (https://i.stack.imgur.com/axvI6.jpg) ... so i asked for an efficient method to go for.

Comment: @JakeP, no , i want to know the number of times , the y value raised from 0 to 255 or fallen from 255 to 0, which is 14 in the above plot

Answer (score 0):

If the only values possible in your data, as you stated in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57433006/counting-triggers/57448963#comment101349542_57433006) are `0` and `255`, you can write

```
count = sum((s-r)!=0 for r, s in zip(data[0::], data[1::]))
```

taking advantage that in Python booleans are a subclass of integers with possible values equal to `0` or `1`.